# How to make fabric flush the it's output?

Tags: fabric

I'm using fabric to run ssh tasks on remote machines.

The output isn't flushed automatically, is there a method to force auto flushing?

(the documentation doesn't appear to mention this subject)

Answer (score 1):

When using Fabric's `puts()` to output some text, you can use the `flush=True` parameter to avoid buffering:

```
puts('Doing stuff', flush=True)
```

Or if you're concerned about the output from a remote command, you may want to flush the standard output after running the command:

```
run('some command')
sys.stdout.flush()
```

Note that some buffering may still occur in Fabric during execution of the command itself (not sure about it though), or within the remote command itself. In that case, you should see the same behavior when running it through Fabric or directly via SSH.

Comment: The issue is with flushing the output of a long running remote command during execution.
The problem isn't with the remote command itself, as the output is flushed when using other ssh clients.

Answer (score 0):

I'm slightly biased because I work there but we came up with a logging utility for fabric named `gusset` at my workplace. It's named [gusset](https://github.com/locationlabs/gusset) and it allows you to have configurable logging with your fabric scripts

```
from fabric.api import run
from gusset.output import with_output

@with_output(verbosity=1)
def foo():
    run("ls")


In [9]: with settings(host_string="mybox", user="myuser"):
   ...:     foo()
   ...:     
[mybox] run: ls
```